# Foundation 5: removing a gap at the left of my column

Tags: zurb-foundation

I want to get rid of the gap at the left of my green button on [this screenshot](http://uppix.com/f-shot5446475b0017edab.jpg). I can't seem to find any way to remove it.

Markup:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="small-4 medium-5 large-4 columns">          
        <a class="button" id="enroll_in_mooc" href="#">Enroll in MOOC</a>   
    </div>

    <div class="small-6 medium-5 large-6 columns">      

        <ul class="small-block-grid-1 large-block-grid-2" id="jason_computing_features_list"> 
            <li id="jason_computing_self_paced">Self-paced</li>
            <li id="jason_computing_hours_week">4 hours a week</li>
            <li id="jason_computing_assignments">3 Assignments</li>
            <li id="jason_computing_challenges">18 Challenges</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

aa

Answer (score 1):

By default, Foundation applies a right and left padding to columns. I've created a snippet with a couple of options. You can target the column; or simply create a class and add a rule for left-padding.

```css
/* -- target the first-child column -- */
.row .columns:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}

/* -- create a class ('button-enroll' for example ) -- */
.button-enroll {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.4.6/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">

    <div class="small-4 medium-5 large-4 columns button-enroll">          
        <a class="button" id="enroll_in_mooc" href="#">Enroll in MOOC</a>   
    </div>

    <div class="small-6 medium-5 large-6 columns">      

        <ul class="small-block-grid-1 large-block-grid-2" id="jason_computing_features_list"> 
            <li id="jason_computing_self_paced">Self-paced</li>
            <li id="jason_computing_hours_week">4 hours a week</li>
            <li id="jason_computing_assignments">3 Assignments</li>
            <li id="jason_computing_challenges">18 Challenges</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I create a no-m-p class i can apply to any element to completely remove Foundations margin and padding: .no-m-p {margin: 0; padding: 0;}. You can use .collapse in a row, but that is more drastic and also removes spacing between columns which you don't always want.